# Utilizando Promises e Deffered no cotidiano

Tags: javascript, jquery, promises

estou estudando sobre estes itens e estou com dúvidas em como aplica-lás em meus projetos.
Atualmente utilizo callback para tudo porém a estrutura do código fica tensa.. e na internet encontrei bastante artigos falando sobres as Promises e Deffered.. porém não consegui entender como que ficaria na prática isto..

Se não for abusar, mas já abusando, gostaria de entender como que ficaria a seguinte situação, tenho 3 funções e cada uma possui um callback, sendo assim a funcão 2 só é chamada quando a função 1 termina e me retorna o callback de seus dados, assim a função 2 executa e depois chama a função 3, e desta maneira sucessivamente para mais funções caso tivesse.

Então meu código ficaria da seguinte maneira (esse código é um exemplo apenas)

```
function funcao1(callback){
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: minhaUrlPost,
                data: {
                  acao: 'CarregaDadosCliente',
                  codigo: codigo
                },                            
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (json){
                  return callback(json);
                },error: function (){
                  alert("deu erro")
                }
    });
}

function funcao2(cod_cliente,callback){
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: minhaUrlPost,
                data: {
                  acao: 'CarregaPedidosCliente',
                  codigo: cod_cliente
                },                            
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (json){
                  return callback(json);
                },error: function (){
                  alert("deu erro")
                }
    });
}

function funcao3(cod_pedido,callback){
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: minhaUrlPost,
                data: {
                  acao: 'CarregaItensPedidoCliente',
                  codigo: cod_pedido
                },                            
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (json){
                  return callback(json);
                },error: function (){
                  alert("deu erro")
                }
    });
}

funcao1(function(json){
    funcao2(json.cod_cliente, function(json){
        funcao3(json.cod_pedido, function(json){
            //faz alguma coisa ou chamaria mais functions...
        });
    });
});
```

O exemplo acima funciona... porém sei que pode melhorar tanto essa estrutura como o método de trabalho utilizado. e gostaria da ajuda da comunidade para conseguir entender melhor isto na prática do exemplo acima.

Agradeço antecipadamente!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá.
Se as chamadas forem muito semelhantes você pode fazer algo assim:

```
var url = '/echo/json/';
var acao = 'CarregaDadosCliente';
var dados = {acao: acao,codigo: null};

function funcao1(json,nom_cod){
    dados.codigo = typeof nom_cod === 'undefined' ? '' : json[nom_cod];

    $.post(url, dados, function(json){
        return json;
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("deu erro");
    });
}


alert(funcao1(funcao1(funcao1(),'cod_cliente'),'cod_pedido'));
```

Pode até adicionar como parâmetro a url e ação se forem diferentes.
Segue [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r8n69zv0/).

Uma outra ideia seria criar uma função que recebe um array de objetos como:

```
[{url:'url1',acao:'acao1',cb:funcao2},{url:'url2',acao:'acao2',cb:funcao3}]
```

Esta função seria recursiva e retira um item do array a cada fim de chamada.

Eu nunca precisei utilizar o Promises (apenas por curiosidade) utilizei este link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/?redirect_from_locale=pt

Na parte de "Error Handling" tem um exemplo muito bom de chamadas assíncronas aninhadas. Veja se ajuda.